Dog dumps some food from bowl and then eats the rest
So, we have a pair of sibling husky-Cocker Spaniel mix dogs, a boy and a girl.  The girl has started dumping part of the food from her bowl and leaving it, eating what remained in the bowl.  Any idea why she's doing this and how to stop it?

This can be completely normal for Huskies (speaking from experience). What kind of food are we talking about?

Sorry for not replying sooner.  We've tried various foods with different flavors and price points.  They seem to prefer regular old Purina Beneful.

is she a rescue - it could be something she used to do before

She's probably a picky eater or has a bad tooth.
Dogs have preferences for certain flavors - just like humans - and some dogs are picky eaters. They take the food in their mouth and if they don't like it, they simply drop it again. In my experience this is most pronounced if you mix wet and dry food or different kinds of dry food. My own dog likes to eat the wet food first (of course) and if there's some kibble in the way, she spits it out. Only later when she ate all the good stuff will she eat the kibble she spat out earlier.
Amother possibility is that some of the kibble is harder than the rest (maybe because it's bigger or more compressed). If she has a dental problem, the harder kibble can cause her pain, so she spirs it out.

But she's not spitting it out.  She's dumping part of the bowl on the floor and eating the rest of what's in the bowl.  Very odd.

You say you have two "husky-Cocker Spaniel mix dogs"  and you have "tried various foods with different flavors and price points. They seem to prefer regular old Purina Beneful."
Both of these dogs are great hunters/ retrievers.  High spirited and lovely dogs.  I have made many mistakes on my dog food journey.  Initially with a part cocker spaniel, we fed them mostly chicken breast and a little kibble.  Then almost all kibble.
That was for the first year of their lives. Vets don't do a lot of dog nutrition study, but they sell a lot of packaged dog food. Dog food only has to be 18% protein (from any source)  and that is mostly cheap grain filler.
Dogs typically prefer wet commercial food, to kibble. But the same lack of MEAT and offal are in both varieties because large corporates like large profits. Your can of commercial dog food doesn't have to say how much meat (as a percentage) is inside. Just the order of ingredients (which can easily fool people with 'ingredient splitting' tricks)
We moved over to a mostly raw meat diet (plus cooked chicken meat), chicken necks (for the calcium and phosphorus) and offal. We knew what actual nutrition he was getting.  We know that dried meat is typically 60% protein plus and very bio-available.
There are few dogs who hate meat.  Its just a cost thing. If you aren't able to slowly change over to a more raw or even cooked meat/ offal diet, then have you considered at least sprinkling 100% single ingredient offal like beef liver throughout the kibble? Good dog treat companies sell dried offal in the form of liver, kidney, spleen, lung etc. The smell is what really entices a dog, and it happens to be naturally good for them.
That might seem overwhelming for you at the moment, but if mixed thoroughly this can convert many picky eaters.
Hope that helps.

That dosen't quite explain why she's dumping out part of the food and eating the rest. It seems like a more general answer on dog food

if its all the same food (ie exact same looking and smelling kibble) - then yes that is a behavioral issue probably.  They dont seem to be hiding it for later.  I can tell you though, that very few dogs dump meat next to their bowl.  If it is truly mixed food (dry and wet commercial for instance) - then they are just showing preference.  Studies show that most dogs prefer wet over dry. But from the same manufacturer, neither are likely to be any more nutritious than the other.

What is causing this?
Very odd behaviour is sometimes the cause of something unexpected happening once where they needed to adapt their actions to accommodate the circumstance. That adaptation gets associates as the "normal action to do" going forward every time. This seems to be even more common with huskies, they choose to remember very particular things and get "stuck" thinking that's always going to be the scenario.

An example of this: my dog (also husky) used to walk straight down a gravel path that led to a gate. One day, after heavy rain fall, there was a large puddle covering the gravel path. She put one foot in the puddle and then jumped to the side to walk on the grass instead, wanting to avoid the water. Now, every time I walk through this gravel path, she moves to the side and only walks along the grass at that particular spot — even though there's been no puddle and has been dry for months.

A memory of a previous event can cause them to behave irrationally until they've relearned or become confident enough that it won't happen again. Without knowing the exact reason that could have triggered this behaviour the first time, it might be difficult to completely unlearn the behaviour. Unfortunately, it's probably impossible to really know what could have triggered this reaction (maybe a bug was in her food one day or something about the type of food like the other answers mention).
What to do next?
Apart from trying alternate foods (with varying degrees of protein amounts)
or adding toppers to the food as the other answers mentioned, I would try changing her bowl and feeding location. For a quick and cheap test to try:

Use a towel instead of a bowl. Lay down the towel on the floor and spread her food across the towel evenly. For additional mental stimulation you can twist, scrunch, fold or roll up the towel and turn it into a sniffing food puzzle.
Use a household bowl or container (that's a different shape maybe)
Consider buying a slow feeding bowl (it has grooves and shapes built within the bowl so the dog has to work through the cracks to get the food).

